# How can I insert the same number of measured values per case in Excel or SPSS, with days without measurement inserted as 'NA'?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Problem: I have a measured therapy score per day from +/- 1000 patients. However, not every patient has been measured on all days. Is it possible to automatically insert these missing days for each patient, filled in as 'NA' (not applicable)? This way the measured scores in the table after conversion are still linked to the correct day.

At the moment the measured values are consecutive after conversion from 'long-to-wide', while the measurements were not taken on consecutive days.

[Original table with long-data; some days miss a score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvVQ1.png)

Goal: as many "measured" days per patient, with missing values entered as "NA" or X. Also okay to have the data in a long-data form, as long as after conversion to wide data and days are still linked.

[Goal: wide-table with as much data per patient; up to a minimum of 14 days; all days have either a score or 'NA'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW4Re.png)

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and show an example of the input data you use, the actual result you get and the expected result. What format is the input? CSV? Excel?

Comment: It is not clear from your post what "SPSS", "long-to-wide" and "conversion" is, nor what is implied by the goal "as many measured days per patient". It would really help if you can edit your question, and copy and paste screenshots into the question to demonstrate the format of your input and output (desired) data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's been at least 15 years since I last used SPSS, but even back then I think it could do the type of data manipulation you are asking. And yes you can do this in excel also with formulas (as an answer suggests), power query, or VBA. You'll have to be more specific or your question will get closed. Finally, we are not a free service providing scripts. We help you identify issues with what you have.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about the problem here?

Comment: I added a screenshot from the original dataset (1) and the goal (2). Hopefully this makes my problem a bit more clear. If not, i'm glad to add more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Making some crude assumptions here, but you can, depending on the format of your data "regenerate" the complete set of data in a new sheet using the VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP functions. Something like:

```
=LOOKUP(*patient ID*, today!$A$2:$D$1000,2,FALSE)
```

Which would automatically return the #N/A error if it has not been found in the original set of data.